# How to unit test react hooks by shallow mounting React Functional components?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

Is there a way to test functional components built using React hooks by shallow mounting the component. I came across Enzyme not supporting `useEffect` (https://airbnb.io/enzyme/#react-hooks-support)  and other hooks with shallow rendering a component and I don’t want to get into mount.

Also came across `react-testing-library` being a new and popular alternative. Is it better option compared to Enzyme? I already have `Enzyme` used for testing class based components. So, there is a pain involved in rewriting those.

Comment: Any reason why you do not want to fully render it? Even though it is troublesome to use `mount` (especially if you are rendering a connected component), I still think it is the most straight forward way to test its behaviour

Comment: @wentjun I would like to separately test each component as a unit hence shallow is what I prefer.

Comment: Ahh I see.. Makes sense. I would have preferred shallow rendering in that scenario as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can but will need to use **spies**. For example if you are using `jest` you can you use [jest.spyOn](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) with [mockImplementationOnce()](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationoncefn), It should also work with other `spying` libraries.

**Using Example:**

```js
describe("React useEffect", () => {
  let useEffect, wrapper

  let mockUseEffect = () => {
    useEffect.mockImplementationOnce(f => f())
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    useEffect = jest.spyOn(React, "useEffect")

    mockUseEffect()
    wrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent />)
  })

  it("your test", () => {
     // using wrapper
  })
}
```

Here is a nice detailed [article](https://blog.carbonfive.com/2019/08/05/shallow-testing-hooks-with-enzyme/) by "Will Ockelmann-Wagner" and I added a **[codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-useeffect-with-enzyme-01xjy)** working example.

---

Although it works, I'd encourage you to **not** use `shallow` rendering and start using `react-testing-library` (called [@testing-library/react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/react) nowadays), Its well-documented, lightweight Testing solution, and I'd say its the the "closest" test you can get to real world scenarios. It comes already with [CRA](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) by default.

Here a basic **[codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-useeffect-with-testing-library-xek4o)** example and Here is more [examples](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#timers) from React Docs.

Also, here is a great [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LHUdxkThTM0) by [Kent C. Dodds](https://github.com/kentcdodds) that addressing the differences between `shallow` rendering and the `render` approach from react testing library.

Comment: Thanks for nicely explained answer! Read about react-testing-library recently. Found that it uses full mount and doesn't support shallow. If thats the case even enzyme is good to test hooks in functional components using mount. Why react-testing-library then?

Comment: I wasn't actually talking about hooks only but generally speaking why should you consider using RTL for your tests. RTL is like forcing you to write better testing logic and not to do "shallow" tests that might focus on implementation rather than the functionality of your components. Its about the perspective actually not the way.

Comment: For instance, when rendering a component using Enzyme, it allows you to access the full component’s data (props, state, children, …) which mostly leads you to test its implementation, RTL has a different approach, you only have access to the elements that are in the DOM, no internal state, no methods, just what the user can interact with. Thus, that would leads you to rethink of how and what to test. RTL tests are more focused on the end user behavior.

Comment: "We recommend using React Testing Library which is designed to enable and encourage writing tests that use your components as the end users do.

Alternatively, Airbnb has released a testing utility called Enzyme, which makes it easy to assert, manipulate, and traverse your React Components’ output." [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html)

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful details/thoughts. Cheers. I am tempted to get my hands dirty with RTL now.

Comment: I'm really glad that I could help. Btw, Kent C. Dodds (the RTL author) has a great [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/user/kentdoddsfamily) channel with tons of professional and very useful content.